# Null conditional result type, am I missing something?

Tags: c#, resharper, nullable

if (Station?.SeparateJob) gets flagged and I'm not understanding why.

Resharper is happy with if (Station?.SeparateJob == true) and normally it would flag the == true.

I thought null was supposed to evaluate to false in this situation but I'm being told I can't cast a nullable to bool like this.

Comment: Remember that the output is a nullable bool which allows an implicit conversion when compared with a non-nullable bool.

Answer (score 3):

C# does not allow coercion of `null` to `false`, nor the coercion of nullable types to their non-nullable counterparts.

`Station?.SeparateJob` evaluates to a `bool?`.  (It has to, because if `Station` is `null`, then the result is `null`.)  An if statement cannot be performed on a `bool?`, and a `bool?` cannot be implicitly converted to a `bool`, so the compiler emits an error.

However, the statement `Station?.SeparateJob == true` is allowed, since nullable types can be *compared* to their non-nullable counterparts.  This comparison returns `true` if the left side is `true`, and `false` if the left side is `false` or `null`.  The result of the comparison is a true `bool` (not nullable), so the if statement compiles.

Resharper will flag cases where you compare a `bool` to `true` (since it's unnecessary), but does not flag cases where you compare a `bool?` to true (because it is required).

Comment: Yeah, that's the behavior I am observing.  It's just my understanding of the null-conditional operand is that it shouldn't be needed.